# Groovy access script variable from application

Tags: groovy, groovyshell, groovyscriptengine

Need to access the variable defined in the groovy script file
Before executing the script using `GroovyShell`
However, I am getting error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: _THREADS for class: Test1
```

```
//Test1.groovy

_THREADS=10;
println("Hello from the script test ")
```

```
//scriptRunner.groovy

File scriptFile = new File("Test1.groovy");
def sharedData = new Binding()
def shell = new GroovyShell(sharedData)
def script = shell.parse (scriptFile);

def thread = script.getProperty('_THREADS'); // getting ERROR --
// No such property: _THREADS for class: Test1
//-------

//now run the threads
script.run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got the solution using `@Field` modifier value can be accessed after parsing

```
import groovy.transform.Field
@Field _THREADS=10
```

```
File scriptFile = new File("Test1.groovy");
def sharedData = new Binding()
def shell = new GroovyShell(sharedData)
def script = shell.parse (scriptFile);

def thread = script.getProperty('_THREADS'); //value is accessible
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to run script before getting property/binding

```
def sharedData = new Binding()
def shell = new GroovyShell(sharedData)
def script = shell.parse (''' _THREADS=10 ''')
script.run()

println script.getProperty('_THREADS')
```

try to open `AST Browser (Ctrl+T)` in groovy console for this code:

```
_THREADS=10
```

and you'll see approximately following generated class:

```
public class script1663101205410 extends groovy.lang.Script { 
    public java.lang.Object run() {
        _THREADS = 10
    }
}
```

where `_THREADS = 10` assigns property into binding

however it's possible to define _THREADS as a function then it will be accessible without running script.

```
def sharedData = new Binding()
def shell = new GroovyShell(sharedData)
def script = shell.parse (''' def get_THREADS(){ 11 } ''')

println script.getProperty('_THREADS')
```

Comment: Thanks, however, I need the user to define the values in the same script. read those values before executing the script